# How to enable "Change Language Key" on 5.7 QtVirtualKeyboard?

Tags: qt, keyboard, qml

I've built the QtVirtualKeyboard from source, and I've added CONFIG += lang-all to every .pro file in there, yet when I run an example the button is still greyed out.

How do I get the languages button shown here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/user-guide.html to work?

Comment: Which arguments did you pass to qmake when you built the module?